# Develop an app for a website i have no access to

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I'm thinking about developing a mobile app(Windows Phone) for my schools student webpage.
The official website tells you which classes you have, homework, absent and such.
The website is www.elevplan.dk
There is already multiple apps for both Android and iOS (un-official) so i know it's possible, i just simply don't know where to start. 
So, my question is, how can i do this? 
The webpage is personal, and not static, so you will be granted after a login.
I'm possible thinking html 5.

Answer (score 0):

If the site doesn't expose any API, you can always write a program that visits it like a browser and gets/posts data. One of libraries that can be used for this is [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). It supports ssl/cookies etc., so you can log in to access restricted content too. The downside of this approach is that with each major change of the site you'll have to update your application.

Comment: Thanks, so your suggestion is to make the app native, and then gather the info via curl?
Well, lucklly the website havn't been updated for years.

Comment: I didn't really think about pure html option, but it should be possible too (and maybe even easier). I don't know any specific libraries for that though.

Comment: Okay, i just figured out that it seems like the data is gathered by a javascript call in the original elevplan code. So i could possible create something which autenticated you(login) and after that simple gather the javascript data and convert it to a nice layout?

Comment: Search for proper libraries and ways to do it though. For example, if you'd want to do this on normal web site, browser would usually not permit you to make javascript calls to external site, because it would treat it as a possible XSS attack.

Comment: Is it possible to do it nativly though? Let's say i create the design in a native language, and then call the javascript data?

Comment: Yes, for example using curl library. If you're writing html 5 app, not website, then even normal XMLHttpRequest should work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136400/loading-external-files-for-a-non-hosted-html5-application). You could probably use jquery to make this call and later searching resulting tree easier. I'm not an expert in html 5 apps though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know who developed the iOS or Android apps? Simplest approach, in my opinion, would be to get in touch with them and ask them how they did it.

If you really can't get in touch with them, I recommend studying if it is possible to access the data (list of classes, homework, etc.) as a feed, like RSS style. I had to do something similar for a project of my own.

After authenticating a user, see if there are URIs for specific data feeds that you can obtain the data from. Then you just need to translate that data into something you can present in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, there is no rss feed or similar, even though it would be a nice idea.   There is some urls to some of the data, in a javascript language. I might be able to gather the data and set it up nicely.